# jQuery UI: dialog show/hide effects with options

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it possible to specify options for the show and hide options of a Dialog box in jQuery UI.

For example, instead of:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
  show: 'fade'
});
```

Something like:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
  show: {effect: 'fade', speed: 1000}
});
```

(The code above does not, of course, work.)

What I'm really trying to use is the "complete" method inside of the effect, or a callback function, so I can select some text after the effect is done.

If anyone knows, thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        hide: 'fold',
        show: 'blind'
});
```

And set two different effects to hide and show.

You can't use the "complete" method. At the least not with the actual release. That feature is [planned for release 1.9](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/2358)

hope it helps

Answer (score 49):

I don't know how to specify all the options, but I did manage to specify the speed, which is the option you have in your example. I did this as follows:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 250}
hide: {effect: 'fade', duration: 5000}
});
```

duration is the number of milliseconds that the animation will last. I found this out by stepping through the javascript with firebug.

Comment: It is good solution, but comma after show attribute is missing.
Should be show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 250},

Answer (score 2):

To see the options of each effect you can go to http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects and click the Effect you wanna now the specifcs options.
For exemple http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce

Oh and by the way de Fade Effect doesn't have any specif arguments. If you use the Bounce Effect here's a code sample:

```
$( '#dialog' ).dialog({
show: {effect: 'bounce', duration: 350, /* SPECIF ARGUMENT */ times: 3}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that you can specify global effects duration by adding the following in the document.

```
$.fx.speeds._default = duration;
```

duration can be an option ('slow','fast',etc) or a number in miliseconds

Comment: I would think twice before modifying this (internal, note the leading underscore) property, because it will affect all the jQuery-dependent scripts on the page, not only yours.

Comment: You are right, it just works for me because i am using very few effects. If someone is using ui-tabs for example ,the transition would be very slow with a   >1000ms duration

Answer (score 0):

position: { my: "bottom", at: "center", of: window} means that the bottom side going up to center of the dispayed window

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
snippet.dialog({
open: function(event, ui) {
    snippet.hide(); 
    snippet.fadeIn(); 
}});
```