# Mixing Hover and Show Effects for jQuery Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to show a jquery dialog with an effect when the user hovers over a navigation tab and I'm running into some hiccups. When the the mouse is hovered over the first navigation tab, the dialog box shows up with the effect happening on the text. When hovering out, the text in the dialog box slides out of view, but the dialog container remains. How do I make it so that the dialog box as a whole performs the effect rather than the text in the dialog box.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#dialog").hide();  
  $("#1").hover(function(){
  $( "#dialog" ).show('slide', {direction:"down"},400).dialog({ dialogClass: 'removeX'  });
  },function(){
  $( "#dialog" ).hide('scale',{direction:"up"},400).dialog({ dialogClass: 'removeX' });
  });
});
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/538ex/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of the `show` and `hide` dialog options:

```
          show: {
              effect: 'blind', 
              duration: 1000
          }
          ,hide: {
              effect: 'blind', 
              duration: 1000 
          }
```

Also, you can achieve the desired effect with `blind` instead of `slide` and `direction down`.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/538ex/14/)

Also, see [jQuery UI: dialog show/hide effects with options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951729/jquery-ui-dialog-show-hide-effects-with-options)

Comment: With that, the dialog doesn't hide with the blind effect, it merely just disappears. I was able to find a solution, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to figure out the solution on my own. You can set `resizable` to `false`, hide the outline width and set the border to hidden. Here is the updated jQuery, CSS, and fiddle:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#dialog").hide();  
 $("#1").hover(function(){
 $( "#dialog" ).show('slide', {direction:"down"},400).dialog({ dialogClass: 'removeX',
```

resizable: false});
     },function(){
     $( "#dialog" ).hide('scale',{direction:"up"},400).dialog({ dialogClass: 'removeX',
                                                             resizable: false});
     });
    });

CSS:

```
.removeX .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {display: none }
.removeX .ui-dialog-titlebar {display: none }
.removeX {
outline-width: 0px !important;
border:hidden;
}
```

It is important to note that if you want to change properties, don't change it with the dialog id (`#dialog`) instead of the `.removeX' dialog class.

```
#dialog{
background:lightblue;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle with the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/538ex/13/